# Customizing my own SQL statement using Yii

Tags: php, sql, function, yii

Yes I read the documentation, but sometimes I also need help from something that doesn't come from a book.

I'm trying to write a script that sends an email to all users within the database whenever the admin posts a new blog entry. Here is my code so far:

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model=new TbPost;

    // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
    // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

    if(isset($_POST['TbPost']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['TbPost'];

        $this->emailAll();

        if($model->save())
            $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
    }

    $this->render('create',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}



//email all Function

public function emailAll()
{
    //assuming that id is from the email table(unless email is under a members table)
    $sql = mysql_query("select email from tb_user");

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {

        $to = $row['emailAdd'];
        $subject = 'NEW UPDATE FROM ADMIN';
        $message = 'HELLO TEST';
        $headers = 'From: WEBMASTER@b.com' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'BCC: ' . implode(', ', $to) . "\r\n";


        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    }
}
```

the first function "actionCreate" is yiis generated function and I added "$this->emailAll();" to call the function I created to email all users whenever there is a new create.

Problem is, I know that the sql won't work because yii has its own way of connecting to the database and I'm not sure how I would do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the part of the documentation you are looking for: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.query-builder#building-data-retrieval-queries

Also, a suggestion. It generally is easier to test your logic in the future if it isn't embedded in controllers.

Probably worth moving your code out of your controller. There are a few places you could out it, but I would suggest creating a CActiveRecordBehavior, watching the afterSave event and sending out an email (including a link to the post?) after your post model has saved.

Comment: Thank you for the link to the section. It makes more sense now.

Comment: @charlesisjan sure, no problem. Would appreciate an accept if this helped answer your question

Answer (score 0):

In my response, I am assuming you have a model for users as well. If you don't, then you should create one.

Your query can be converted to the Yii form like this

```
$rsltAllmails = User::model()->findAll();
```

This should an array of objects, each one representing a single row of the query results. You can process them as follows :

```
foreach ($rsltAllmails as $recEmail) {
   $to = $recEmail->emailAdd;
   // ...
   // ...and others ...
   // ...
}
```